# How to avoid paying for the same item multiple times

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm trying to draw a database design of an ecommerce, and fulfilment of order platform. The company currently has a distribution centre for fulfilling the orders. But they want to extend this to use its stores for a part of the fulfilment process. I have designed a database of "internet sales" and "store sales", but I am stuck on the fulfilment of the internet order, and I wonder if any of you can help me with this.

**Scenario :** When the customer places in an order, and the distribution centre doesn't have a stock of an item to ship to the customers, the item needs to be taken from one of the stores. This item is then sent to the customer.

But the problem is that I can't just take an item from a store, and then send it to the customers, because the item hasn't been sold in the store, its (store) stock database isn't going to be updated. If I put the item through the cash machine, the item is removed from the stock table, but there are two transactions for the same item - one transaction from the internet, and the other from the store.

I guess my question is, how do I go about processing internet orders, and avoid having two transactions on the same item?

Any helpful pointers on this issue is greatly appreciated.

**Update :** Here's what I have done so far after advice from Jo Douglass,

[Database Design Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UYtL.jpg)

Sorry, I can't post images, because I don't have enough points. And please note that the above database design isn't complete

Comment: I've answered, but it's fairly high-level; without seeing your existing model it's difficult to give a more detailed answer. If you're still not sure how to tackle this after reading my answer, comment on my answer and let me know. If you can edit your question to show the relevant parts of your existing model it will assist in adding further detail to my answer, or any other answers that might be posted. Thanks!

Comment: OK - immediate question before I look too much further into the design. Why have you created this with facts and dimensions? Dimensional databases are for data marts or data warehouses - i.e. downstream reporting and analytics functionality like business intelligence. Databases for use with transactional systems are generally more normalized, and don't have the concept of facts or dimensions.

Comment: Because of legacy database, I have done that. I will be  required to pull data from the old database, and keep historical data for reporting. It is one of business requirements.

Comment: Are you using this as the main database for the system as well, though?  In your original question you seemed to be discussing a database for a live system, rather than a reporting database.

Comment: No, this isn't going to be used as the main database. This is the order fulfilment process for the distribution centre and the store. They will be looking at these data, and then they will print out the labels and send the parcels to the respective customers. I am sorry for any confusion, I didn't mean to do that.

Comment: If this is purely a reporting database - i.e. a *copy* of the original data, and the front end of your system(s) don't interact with it (except perhaps for reporting purposes) - then I'm not too clear on what your question is. Why would you need to run items through the cash register? For a data warehouse you have ETL processes which copy data from your transactional database(s) to the warehouse. You might need to implement some data cleansing processes if your issue is that the transactional database is creating records which don't make sense from a reporting perspective.

Comment: Given this string of comments, I would recommend that you revisit your question and make a few edits. Explain what databases are involved, which of these databases you are looking to create or make changes to, and what the usage of each database is (i.e. is each database used as the data store of a transactional system, a data warehouse, or both?). Once it's clear whether you're wanting to change a transactional system and its database, or whether you only want to change a downstream reporting database, this question will be a lot more straightforward to answer.

Comment: I saw things bit different, before your advice - The shops are acting as a distribution center for the internet sales. When an item is sent from the shop to the customers, the shop stock is down by one item. Every day, the shop has to do end of day sales report, and that means that the item is not going to show on the report unless it is sold in that day. During shop stock audit, the shop database will have more stock than physical stock. This is a nightmare for the account department. That is why I have said that I need to run it through the cash register to show the stock has been sold.

Comment: ...But the problem now is that the same stock has been sold twice

Comment: OK, that's a clearer explanation of the problem - but I'm still not sure whether you have two separate databases (one which the shop transactional system or systems use, plus a separate reporting database), or one database which is being used for both the transactional system and the reporting.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple databases. The internet sales, has its own database, and each shop, has its own local database

Comment: Honestly, I think this is well beyond being a database design question. If your shop systems need some way to be able to show that they have removed an item from inventory in order to send that to a customer, then implement some new logic which allows them to do that. If this then needs to integrate with your internet sales system to show that an order has been fulfilled, then implement some kind of systems integration process to do that. I would strongly advise that you tackle the business process and integration issues as such, and not just think about it as a database issue.

Comment: Once you've figured out how to deal with the process and integration issues, then you *might* find one or more of your databases need changing - at which point, fair enough, ask how to reflect the business and systems changes in one or more databases. Also, I would still recommend that you do not use a dimensional model for a database if it is being used for anything other than reporting, business intelligence, & data analysis.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a Transaction entity, and you have or are planning on having some logic which ensures that when one of these is created for an Item, your system knows to deplete the stock level for the relevant location (either a store of the distribution centre).

You could use an entity which shows an Item being transferred from one location (a store) to another (a distribution centre), and then create some logic which works very similarly to your existing logic - depleting the stock level in the starting location, and increasing the stock level in your destination location. Then when you carry out the last part of the process (sending the item to the customer), you'll have a Transaction showing that and depleting the distribution centre's stock level. Depending on the rest of your model, you might carry this out via a change to the Transaction entity, or by creating a new entity altogether.

Alternatively, if that doesn't really model what's happening in the business very well, then maybe you just need to modify your logic (and possibly your model - hard to tell without seeing your existing model). Rather than only being able to create store transactions via use of the cash register, perhaps you simply need to be able to create a store transaction that's been kicked off via the Internet.

Comment: ‎Thanks for that. I have revised the database design according to your advice on it, and have provided a link to the image. If you can then please give me your opinion on it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to go ahead and treat the item as sold from the store (through an online transaction) and credit the store's account with the sale price. The distributor has probably already received the wholesale price from the store so it's happy, the store gets credit for the sale (with at least some part of the shipping charges) so it's happy, and you don't have to create new transaction codes or any other modification to the existing database.